# hwclock -s in rc.local wont work

Tags: raspbian

i connect RTC to raspberry and when i execute thiese command time set correctly without internet connection :

```
echo ds3231 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
hwclock -s
```

but when i add these command to `rc.local` Rpi time wont set and `date` show `Thu Jan  1 03:30:33 IRST 1970`

and after boot i must manually enter only `sudo hwclock -s` to time set ...

why only `hwclock -s` wont execute in `rc.local` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, you need to add `sudo` before the `hwclock -s` command. Don't ask me why, since I have no idea. I was under the impression that rc.local is always run at highest privileges, but apparently that does not apply to hwclock. Infact most of the other commands I run in rc.local work without sudo. But not hwclock.